# Can't Upload Video Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, video

I tried to upload a video using codeigniter 3. but why I got an error **"Column 'file' cannot be null"**
I have checked my codes, nothing wrong.. Please help me.
here is my code

**Model**

```
 public function savevideo(){
    $post = $this->input->post();
    $this->file = $this->UploadVideo();
    return $this->db->insert($this->_tableigavideo, $this);
 }
 private function UploadVideo(){
    $config['upload_path']          = './video';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'MP4';
    $config['overwrite']            = true;
    $config['max_size']             = 17500000; 

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ($this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
        return $this->upload->data("file_name");
    }
}
```

**Here is my Controller**

```
public function addvideo(){
    $indikator = $this->IndikatorModel;
    $validation = $this->form_validation;
    $validation->set_rules($indikator->rules());

    if ($validation->run() == TRUE){
     $indikator->savevideo();
     $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Berhasil upload video');
     redirect('indikator/index/'.$idiga);
    }
}
```

**Here is my View**

```
      <label class="col-form-label col-sm-3" for="file"><b>Pilih File Mp4/Mov</b></label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="file" name="file" accept=".mp4">
      </div>
```

Comment: and I got this error "POST http://localhost:8080/indikator/addvideo/12 500 (Internal Server Error)" in inspect element

Comment: have you set enctype="multipart/form-data" in `form` element? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean

Comment: Code Snippets are not meant to be used to format your code! Code Snippets are runable 

**JavaScript**, **CSS** and **HTML** code blocks to help to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example!
 

[About Code Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) 
and [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0):

Check your database.. set your file column to null if you are not always sending image file. And if your are sending image file always then check it is going to db or not. Print statement and check.